# python script not work with incron

Tags: python

```
incrontab -e
/home/owen/file_to_be IN_ALL_EVENTS /home/owen/abc.py 

owen@desktop:~$ cat abc.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
p = open('file_to_test', 'a+')
p.write("test")
p.close()

owen@desktop:~$ ll file_to_test file_to_be 
-rw-r--r-- 1 owen owen 32 2012-04-27 17:07 file_to_be
-rw-r--r-- 1 owen owen 60 2012-04-27 17:07 file_to_test

owen@desktop:~$ echo "a" >> file_to_be 
owen@desktop:~$ ll file_to_test file_to_be 
-rw-r--r-- 1 owen owen 34 2012-04-27 17:15 file_to_be
-rw-r--r-- 1 owen owen 60 2012-04-27 17:07 file_to_test


owen@desktop:~$ tail -n 3 /var/log/syslog
Apr 27 17:15:01 owen1 CRON[12003]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr 27 17:15:10 owen1 incrond[11574]: table for user owen changed, reloading
Apr 27 17:15:18 owen1 incrond[11574]: (owen) CMD (/home/owen/abc.py)
```

It seems incron has been triggered

But the python script didn`t work as expect.

Anyone know why?

If I execute abc.py, it will append "test" to file correct.

Comment: It's not a solution to your problem. But closing the file object is just good habit. You can use the close method on the file object. Or even better, use pythons with-statement `with open("file_to_test") as p:` etc...

Comment: Thank you,I did it, but still not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the script is working,but not as you expected... Put the full path to the file generated by the script, i.e.:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 p = open('/tmp/file_to_test', 'a+')
 p.write("test")
 p.close()
```

Then check than the file '/tmp/file_to_test' is generated, the problem can be the environment that uses incron to run the script.

Comment: For the explanation, the problem comes from the current working directory when the script is trigger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601386/incron-on-raspbian-not-working/16865338#16865338

Answer (score 1):

Your script doesn't seem to be executable, you need to use chmod to make it executable (chmod +x abc.py).