# incron on Raspbian not working

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have virtually an identical situation as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348038/python-script-not-work-with-incron), except the accepted answer does not work for me at all. Making this simple Python script is my second attempt; echoing text and redirecting it to a file doesn't do anything either. I am using the Raspbian linux distro.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ incrontab -l
/home/pi IN_CREATE,IN_DELETE /home/pi/test.py

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat test.py 
#! /usr/bin/python3 
f = open('test.txt', 'a+')
f.write('success!\n')
f.close()

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ touch abc.123; rm abc.123

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ tail -n 3 /var/log/syslog
May 17 00:17:09 raspberrypi incrond[1799]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/test.py )
May 17 00:18:36 raspberrypi incrond[1799]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/test.py )
May 17 00:18:36 raspberrypi incrond[1799]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/test.py )

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ls
bin  Desktop  python_games  test.py
```

Notice the lack of `test.txt` in the home directory.

Comment: umm, shouldn't the first line of `test.py` read `#!/usr/bin/python3`, instead of having a space between the shebang and slash?

Comment: the space doesn't matter

Comment: If you're going to claim the solution doesn't work, at least post what happens when you *apply* the solution, as opposed to what happens when you make the exact same mistake as the asker in the linked question.

Comment: @Cairnarvon I agree with you. By the way, the previous question does not explain exactly *why* an absolute file path fixes the problem. Was not hard to find indeed.

Answer (score 3):

I have tested on a standard Debian Wheezy. The problem your script faces come from the fact that the current working directory (CWD) is not what you expect.

Setting an absolute path in your open operation is a way to avoid it:

```
f = open('/home/pi/test.txt', 'a+')
```

First, I have fear an infinite recursion if events for `test.txt` changes trigger again the script, but it seems to be handled by `incron`.

As stderr is lost when triggered by `incron`,  it is important to test the script manually with `./test.py`.

Here is a variation of your script with additional information thanks to `$@` option:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import sys
import os
f = open('/home/pi/test.txt', 'a+')
f.write('success on ' + sys.argv[1] + ' with CWD=' + os.getcwd() + '\n')
f.close()
```

Which is registered that way:

```
$ incrontab -l
/home/pi IN_CREATE,IN_DELETE /home/pi/test.py $@
```

Now you will see in `/home/pi/test.txt`

```
success on /home/pi/ with CWD=/
```

which explains that your script first tries to write `/test.txt` and has not required permission on file system to do so.